# AngularJS and selects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS in  my project. And I have some interesting task. I have first select with categories and second with sub-categories. When I'm selecting category in other select I want to see just sub-categories that belongs to this category. Categories and subcategories are in DB. Should I use promises and load data before loading a controller and then using click event make another $http request into back-end to select sub-categories? Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: What is the potential size of the data and the collections?  I tend to think that simple and less http requests is better than small bits of data and multiple requests. Thousands of select lists items can be sent under 5k.  The other part is if, do you have logic on the server side? you may have to make individual calls.

Comment: It will be about 10 categories and summary about 100 subcategories. Maybe I should bind click event with calling this data from DB because in back-end I just get this data from DB and send it to Angular in JSON-format.

Comment: Maybe should define global clear java script function not in controller and get info via $http and after that call it in controller initialization.

Comment: If you want to make `conditional fields` in the hundreds of items range, and your data is not dependant on server-side logic to update, just download the whole collection and filter it in angular.  Example - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/kbwxp4tp/